VSC. How to change the gutter background color in Jupyter Notebooks cells?
Searching in the web and here, I can't find how would be the way to change gutter background color specifically in the cells of Notebooks in Visual Studio Code.
The question is mainly because the next code instruction in the settings file, only changes the gutter background color in the editor in general, but not in the Notebooks cells.
"workbench.colorCustomizations":
{
    //...
    "editorGutter.background": "#000000", //Gutter color here.
    //...
}

The Notebooks background cells can be changed with the next instruction, but when the "line numbers" option is activated (File > Preferences > Settings > searching for "line numbers" > Notebook: Line Numbers > on), then the cells keep in a plain background format, so it would be very helpful visually see where exactly starts the left vertical margin for the code.
"workbench.colorCustomizations":
{
    //...
    "notebook.cellEditorBackground": "#000000", //Gutter color here.
    //...
}

Thank you
